# Uipath log file locations

Tags: uipath

Is is possible to change the location of the uipath log files? The reason is ask is that I have built a console application that has I'd like to show a parsed version for certain messages. I have tried looking in the studio application, and I am not familiar with the uipath config file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to change the log file location.Open the **Nlog.xml** file located in UiPath folder in **Program Files(x86)** folder in C drive.

`<variable name="LogDirectory"
value="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/UiPath/Logs"/>`

This is the path of log file. You can edit this path as per your need. Use Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to add your own Log either in your own database SQL/MySQL/ or even in Acces/Excel files